# Add Scroll Bar and select image instead of radio buttons

Tags: wordpress, image, field

I created an options field on my WordPress options page. My field contains 36 images for patterns of my body theme. All things work perfectly.

[image]
How can I add a scroll bar to my options field until it only shows some images, then by scrolling shows other images?

How can I hide radio buttons and select images instead on radio buttons?

This is my code

```
function YPE_body_pattern_callback() {
    ?>
        <div>
            <h3>Choose Pattern</h3>
            <?php
                $checked = 'checked="checked"';
                $YPE_options = get_option( 'YPE_post_option_name' );
            ?>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <?php for($i=1 ; $i<=36 ; $i++ ){ 
                 $pattern = 'body-bg'.$i; ?>
                <li>
                    <input name="YPE_post_option_name[YPE_body_pattern]" type="radio" value="<?php echo $pattern ?>" <?php if($YPE_options['YPE_body_pattern'] == $pattern ) echo $checked; ?> />
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/panel/images/patterns/<?php echo $pattern ?>.png" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the `overflow:scroll;width:300px;` CSS property for adding scroll bar by 300px height.